# AWS Encryption SDK on Java 7

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any way to run AWS Encryption SDK based Application on Java 7 .

As per AWS website To use this SDK you must have: A Java 8 development environment

I am Trying to Run AWS KMS API for ARN Based Encryption Decryption In my application.

Answer (score 0):

No. As per official documentation the pre-requisite are as below:

1. You will need `Java 8` or later.

   *Note: If you use the Oracle JDK, you must also download and install the Java Cryptography Extension (`JCE`) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.*
2. Bouncy Castle jar
3. `AWS SDK for Java` (Optional) - needed if you want to use `AWS KMS` as master key provider.

I would recommend to upgrade to `Java 8` ( if possible).

[AWS encryption SDK developer-guide-java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java.html)